# Undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash>

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, jruby, sinatra

I'd like to store and update blogger labels to datastore in GAE.
When I run that code, I get this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Application Error
/base/data/home/apps/yet-another-problem/1.334886515480009498/WEB-INF/gems/gems/sinatra-0.9.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:45:in `each': undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash:0x86684c> (NoMethodError)
```

### The Code

```
class Labels
   class LabelData
    include Bumble
    ds :blog_element_labels
   end

  def update
    response = URLFetch.get($label_url)
    result = response.to_s
    result_headless = result.gsub("listLabels(",'')
    pure_result = result_headless.gsub(");",'')
    json_to_yaml = YAML::load(pure_result)['entry']['category']

    json_to_yaml.each do |label|
    @label = LabelData.find(:blog_element_labels => label['term'])
    @label = LabelData.create(:blog_element_labels => label['term']) if @label.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

and run by cron job does '/job'

```
get '/job' do
  @labels = Labels.new
  @labels.update
end
```

Where is the problem? Please teach me.

But when run cron job first time, label data was stored, even occur that error.
Could not update data.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think your having the same problem that's been discussed here: [error happens when I try "all" method in datamapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117272/error-happens-when-i-try-all-method-in-datamapper)

In your case, Sinatra is trying to take the return value of @lavels.update and turn that into a string to display to the user.

Try this to see if it fixes the problem:

```
get '/job' do
  @labels = Labels.new
  @labels.update
  "Labels Updated"
end
```

Your return value is now a string, so you shouldn't get the error.

Comment: Thank you vey much !
Fix and works !
Appreciate your light speed answer.

Comment: @tknv, You should mark this answer as Accepted if it fixed your problem, so Luke gets reputation for it.

Comment: @Peter,Sorry delay,Really hard to find where is and how to accept.I tried to find some button for accept,but not.

Comment: Thanks! You fixed my problem with this too! :)